# How to create a list of objects with random x and y co-ordinates in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
listOfObjects = listOfObjects.concat(Array(10000000).fill({l: 50, b: 50, color: "#000000"}).map((s) => {
 s.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (mapSquareSize));
 s.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (mapSquareSize));
 return s;
}));
```

The listOfObjects array should have objects with the properties x,y, l, b and color. I have used the Array fill() function to set the l, b and color variables. I want the x and y co-ordinates to be unique for each object in ListOfObjects. However, the above code just gives the same random x and y co-ordinates to each Object.

I was using this for loop for this purpose, but a friend told me that a solution like this would be way more efficient.

```js
// for (var i = 1 ; i <= 10000000 ; i++)
// {
//     var rock = new Object();
//     rock.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (mapSquareSize)) + 0 ;
//     rock.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (mapSquareSize)) + 0 ;
//     rock.l = 50 ;
//     rock.b = 50 ;
//     rock.color = "#000000";
//     listOfObjects.push(rock);
// }
```

Comment: When you use `Array.fill()` like that, every element in the array will be a reference to the *exact same object*. The `.fill()` approach is not going to be more efficient than your working simple `for` loop anyway.

Comment: Why would it be more efficient?

Comment: @Pointy So, is there a dynamic Array.fill() equivalent that would let me do this?

Comment: Your `for` loop looks fine to me; anything that operates on each element of an array is essentially doing the same amount of work.

Comment: The JS runtime will work more efficiently if you assign all of the properties in one go rather than one at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is `Array.from`:

```
 const result = Array.from({ length: 10000000 }, () => ({
   x: Math.floor(Math.random() * (mapSquareSize)),
   y: Math.floor(Math.random() * (mapSquareSize)),  
   l: 50,
   b: 50,
   color: "#000000",
}));
```

This works as expected and will create a new object during each iteration.  It will do exactly the same as your for loop, it's just a bit more elegant (IMO).

Comment: I've never seen `Array.from({ length: 10000000 }, () => {})` before, that's interesting. Thank you